# Setting up Openfire in MAC OS X

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite, openfire

I have installed openfire 3.9.3 on MAC OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2.
having trouble in setting up openfire. After installing openfire I am getting the error like could not start openfire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get latest version of java (jdk) and install it and install latest version of openfire .its working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

To get started on the installation and setup, you need to grab the most current version of Openfire from the Ignite Realtime web site.

Click [here](http://macs.about.com/od/diyguidesprojects/ss/Create-Your-Own-Jabber-Based-Server_2.htm)! and follow step by step